# Why do I always have to reenable Steam Permissions on my Mac?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, macos

When I launch any Steam games like Cs:Go or TF2, My engine always says that the overlay is not on before launching, causing me to always open up my System preferences and I have to put in the password and double click on the check box next to steam before I play. Is there any way to set steam so that I do not have to do this before each game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Steam updating should not cause permissions to need to be re-enabled.
>   Also, I have noticed this occurs more often than Steam updates. It is
>   more likely an issue with Yosemite that has not been patched in Steam
>   yet. "

(All credit should go to [tubedogg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190839/why-do-i-always-have-to-reenable-steam-permissions-on-my-mac#comment258672_190857).)

Comment: Yea That's what I think it is.

Comment: @Neffer_23 Cool, hope it helped you.

Comment: so there is really no way to fix it. I just have to wait until steam fixes it.

Comment: Yes, but that should happen promptly because they would be losing money and clients if they do not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It happens after a steam update, I believe.

You may be enrolled in Steam beta updates, which would lead to permissions being reenabled everytime Steam or a Steam game starts.

Comment: Steam updating should not cause permissions to need to be re-enabled. Also, I have noticed this occurs more often than Steam updates. It is more likely an issue with Yosemite that has not been patched in Steam yet.

Comment: okay makes sense.